# Changing input value by reference

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So the normal way of handling inputs is to have a state variable for it and change it, like this:

```
    const [title, setTitle] = useState('');
    <Form.Input
        label="Title"
        value={title}
        onChange={(e, data) => {
            setTitle(data.value);
        }}
    />
```

The problem comes when there are more complex forms, and where the complete form is in a single variable and inside many different components.

The way I figured it "works" is to include the object where the value is and the name of the property, that way I can change it (but even then it makes things a bit tricky):

```
    <Form.Input
        inline
        label="Subtitle"
        value={item.instructions_data.subtitle}
        onChange={(e, data) => {
            onChange(item.instructions_data, data.value, 'subtitle');
        }}
    />

    // onChange example
    const onChange = (source, value, field) => {
        source[field] = value;
        setItem(item);
    };
```

This way works, but it is far from elegant and it makes a lot of unnecessary boilerplate.

What is the better way of doing this? Can I somehow get a reference object from event in onChange?

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: When the state gets more and more complex the boilerplate becomes unavoidable. In fact React provides the [useReducer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) hook to manage complex states like this one which is like admitting that that's the suggested way to deal with them

Comment: You can write a small wrapper for the input component and pass the `setX` function as prop: https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-bassi-75tit